Windows 11, VS Code pin workspace to taskbar having "Show recently opened items in Start" disabled
I want to pin a VS Code folder to my task bar but I want to keep disabled the Windows 11 setting to track my recently opened items.
Unfortunately, I cannot find any button to make it happens. The only way I found is to pin the "Show recently opened items in Start, Jump Lists and File Explorer", pin the VS Code workspace and finally to disable it again. As you can imagine it's quite unhandy...

Why not pin the program you use VSC to the task bar instead? It also keeps a list of most recently worked on files.

I'm sorry, what do you mean with "pin the program you use VSC"? What program are you talking about? I want to pin a workspace folder

I have the compilers IDE link (VSC in this case) pinned to the task bar.

Oh ok got it thank you for the tip but it doesn't answer my question. I want to be able to pin workspace (so that on right-click on VSC on taskbar it opens the pinned folders) and let disabled the Windows recent files history
